# MySQL query to return OR-inclusive relationships from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two entities, "User" and "Product", and two tables: One to store which users **viewed** which products and the other to store which users **liked** which products. I want query once and return the results as illustrated below:

Table "Views":

[image: Table Views]

Table "Likes":

[image: Table Likes]

Query result:

[image]

Ideally, there should not be repeated user_id, product_id in the results. Notice that if an user neither viewed nor liked a product it should not be returned (i.e., there should be no FALSE,FALSE rows).

As MySQL does not support FULL JOIN I suspect there should be a workaround using UNION ALL. I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Wouldn't LEFT JOINing both of those tables with the USERS table then grouping be easiest?

Comment: That sounds like right! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, max(`view`) `view`, max(`like`) `like` FROM (
  SELECT user_id, product_id, TRUE `view`, FALSE `like` FROM views
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_id, product_id, FALSE, TRUE FROM likes
) s
GROUP BY user_id, product_id
```

Btw, you should try to avoid `view` and `like` as names as they are reserved words in MySQL.

Bear in mind that in MySQL `true` and `1` as well as `false` and `0` are synonyms.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddffb7/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    v.User_ID, v.Product_ID, true AS `View`, IF (l.User_ID, true, false) AS `Like` 
FROM views v
LEFT JOIN likes l ON (l.User_ID = v.User_ID AND l.Product_ID = v.Product_ID)
UNION
SELECT 
    l.User_ID, l.Product_ID, IF (v.User_ID, true, false) AS `View`, true AS `Like` 
FROM likes l
LEFT JOIN views v ON (l.User_ID = v.User_ID AND l.Product_ID = v.Product_ID)
ORDER BY User_ID, Product_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, 
       'TRUE' AS view_result, 
       CASE WHEN l.user_id IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS like_result 
FROM views AS v
  NATURAL LEFT JOIN likes AS l
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, product_id, 
       'FALSE', 'TRUE'
FROM views AS v
  NATURAL RIGHT JOIN likes AS l
WHERE v.user_id IS NULL ;
```

Tested: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddffb7/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    User_ID,
    Product_ID,
    Views.User_ID IS NOT NULL AS View,
    Likes.User_ID IS NOT NULL AS Like
FROM
    Users
    LEFT JOIN Views USING (User_ID)
    LEFT JOIN Likes USING (User_ID)
WHERE
    Views.User_ID IS NOT NULL
    OR Likes.User_ID IS NOT NULL
```